# WYSIWYG word processor (or other tool) able to generate HTML from a document

Tags: html, word-processor, libreoffice, open-office

I'm looking for a word processor that is also able to produce beautifully-formatted HTML pages from a document.

Something on the line of LibreOffice, which is able to save in XHTML/HTML format, but whose output is a bit rough in my opinion.

It may also not be a word processor -- just a tool able to munch an ODT document and output nice HTML pages (say, one HTML file per chapter).

I've been documenting a piece of open-source software and providing the docs first in PDF (generated by OpenOffice), later via MediaWiki. I would like to find a way to provide both at the same time. I know I could use Sphinx or LaTeX for this but I'd really prefer to compose the documentation on a WYSIWYG software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/) is a WYSIWYG Open Source web authoring software.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a wordpress.org site.  Each documentation topic would be a webpage in wordpress.  (Wordpress gives you a wysiwyg editor.)  Then, install a plugin that makes it easy to create a pdf from a page.